# Is there an automatic gem5 configuration generator based on my Server?

Tags: configuration, automation, gem5

Is there a tool or script that would read my server properties (Number of CPUS, Cores, Memory layout and Structure) and automatically generate a full system mode (FSE) configuration script based on that ?

I know this might little ambitious, but maybe something like that exists somewhere ....

Comment: I wonder if it would be that much harder to just write a parametrized Python config script that creates the setup that you want based on `fs.py` or other scripts.